# std::shared_ptr<void> for converting from and to a custom type

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, visual-studio-2015, shared-ptr

Good afternoon,

So I made a library that needs to be used as an APi for different applications under linux and windows both as a command line tool and a gui.

Inside of that library I have an `std::map` of structures, and it represent physical objects that the program is made to control.

I want to be able to pass it some special class **only** from the windows GUI app, but not from any other apps. And this special class is a direct3D class called `3DModel`

So I believe I cannot reference this class anywhere in the library without using a bunch of `#define _WIN64` and so on. Maybe if I use forward declarations?

The library is also not doing anything at all with the object, the object is created in the Windows GUI app and passed to the library entirely for organization purposes (to prevent creating a duplicated `std::map` structure just to store these objects. And then it's called on by the windows GUI app to render and so on.

The other apps are not creating this object, as they would just pass a `nullptr` to it instead and never use it.

So my question is, Inside the library, can I have function parameters, `std::map` structure, etc use `std::shared_ptr<void>`.

Then in the Windows GUI, I would create an `std::shared_ptr<Model3D>`, cast it to `std::shared_ptr<void>` retrieve it when necessary, cast it to `std::shared_ptr<Model3D>` again, then render with it?

Is this ethical? Are there better alternatives? I heard recommendations of `boost::any`, but haven't used it yet. I don't have boost anywhere in the code yet, are there any standard alternatives?

Or is this a situation where I would forward declare the `3DModel` class in the library, but never `#include "3DModel.h"` ?

Thanks,
-D

Comment: You can't cast from one `shared_ptr` to another. You can have a `shared_ptr` to a *base class*, or you can use raw pointers.

Comment: You could also have a seperate impl of Model3D by platform, with the non-windows ones perhaps just skeleton impls that throw? That way at least the API would be consistent by platform but runtime would be as you described.

Comment: @MarkRansom [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

Comment: @T.C. well done. However I still don't think it's a good idea to cast down to `void`, if you want to go that way you should have a base class.

Comment: @MarkRansom A `std::shared_ptr<void>` is commonly used as a part of type erasure techniques. It's a safer counterpart of the _C-ish_ `void *` you can find in a lot of library used to accommodate user data, as an example. It's a good idea as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks! The base class idea is great, Model3D actually already has a base class, so I could just use that. I cant convert your comments to answers though, so please feel free to submit that as an answer